# Cnft collection token documentation

Tags: metaplex, mint, cnft, umi, bubblegum

I am trying to mint cnfts one by one (no usermint on candy machine) using bublegum and umi and I want them to be part of a collection.

There is documentation about creating tree and how to mint cnft in an existing collection.

But I can't find documentation on how to mint the cnft collection itself.

Is there any? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can check their tests where you can find each one of the steps https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum/tree/main/clients/js/test

Those tests should give me most of the workaround to create the tree, collection and minting

Comment: Thank you for the link!
In the tests, mintToCollectionV1.test.ts would be the place to search how it's done?
Do you know if there is somewhere an example of the metadatas json?
Or are the metadatas of a cnft collection token the same that those of a nft collection token?